# How to set up an SSL reverse proxy within Amazon ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have a web app in a Docker container, and I want to proxy it via another container (running NGINX) that is exposed to the outside world and only handles HTTPS traffic. Both containers would be hosted by ECS on the same EC2 instance. What's the best way to make the NGINX container retrieve the SSL private key from S3 or IAM?

Note that I don't want to include the private key in the Docker image for security reasons. I want to retrieve the private key from S3 or IAM when the container is created, taking the AWS user credentials from environment variables.

[Amazon Elastic Beanstalk has a nice way to achieve this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html#storing-certs), but I don't think there's anything like that for ECS. I'm thinking that I'll need to write a Docker entrypoint (or wrap the Nginx command) in order to install an S3/IAM client and then download the key using the credentials in the environment. Does AWS provide a nicer way? It seems like Elastic Load Balancing is a solution, but I can't find any information regarding the security measures between the LB and the EC2 instance.

Comment: I would say using an external ALB with SSL handling inside a VPC with the ECS EC2 instance is quite a secure solution, but it all depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few parts to the question,

Placing Nginx and web app on the same instance can be achieved by defining both containers as part of the same ecs task. I would recommend creating a docker link from nginx to webapp container.This would allow you to avoid exposing the webapp container port externally. The only port exposed to the host will be the nginx port.

One of the ways to retrieve the Keys securely at the container startup is to have a custom shell script start the nginx service on the container. For this you will need to build your own docker container. In you docker build file define the start of the container using a custom shell script. In the shell script, you can have logic to retrieve the file from s3 using aws cli. After the retrieval you can start the nginx service. Using aws cli will allow you to use the credential available on the ec2 instance.
In case your base docker image does not have aws cli, you will need to add it.